# iOS AFNetworking iPods error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to implement AFNetworking in my application while implementation i got error like this how to resolve this error?

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-Transity-AFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Hi me also getting same errror once you found the solution for this please post on your answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the same problem with the following code.

Add this to the Library Search Paths in Build Settings and make sure you select recursive, delete other library paths which might be absolute paths.

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)
```

May be it will help you.